# No of surveys each customer completed up to the week their next purchase was made

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi friend even this code works for me I am not getting all the customer having data as below . **week_no      Customer_ID   purchase_yn**
                 201728   87697             1
                 201728   87697             1
                 201728   87697             1
                 201732   87697             1
                 201733   87697             0
                 201742   87697             0
                 201743   87697             1
I want out put like below . Number  of distinct weeks  upto second purchase made
 Customer ID    No of weeks 
    87697        2

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: For the customer ID -1 , "PurcahseYn" is 0 for the first record then how could be the "no of weeks" is 3?

Comment: I mean total  survey weeks upto second purchase was made

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using window functions

```
SELECT customerID,
       PurcahseYnCount
FROM   (SELECT *,
               PurcahseYnCount = DENSE_RANK()OVER(partition BY customerID ORDER BY Week_No),
               PurcahseYnSum = Sum(PurcahseYn) OVER(partition BY customerID ORDER BY Week_No)
        FROM   Yourtable) a
WHERE  PurcahseYnSum = 2
```

### Demo

For older versions,

```
SELECT customerID,
       PurcahseYnCount
FROM   (SELECT *,
               PurcahseYnCount = Dense_Rank()OVER(partition BY customerID ORDER BY Week_No),
               PurcahseYnSum = (select Sum(PurcahseYn) from Yourtable b where a.customerID = b.customerID and a.Week_No >= b.Week_No)
        FROM   Yourtable a) a
WHERE  PurcahseYnSum = 2;
```

Comment: @user7854107 - looks like you are using older version. Check the updated the code

Comment: thank you so much .  still i am getting more then one customer id in table with different weeks is there any way we can add group by here .

Comment: @user7854107 - Can you update the question with that sample data and expected result

Comment: Thanksyou so much friends finally following quert works for me
SELECT customer_id,
      min(PurcahseYnCount) NOofweeks
FROM         (SELECT customer_id,
               PurcahseYnCount = DENSE_RANK() OVER(partition BY cusomer_id ORDER BY survey_id),
               PurcahseYnSum = (select Sum(purchase_yn) from survey_response b where a.customer_id = b.customer_id and a.survey_id >= b.survey_id)
        FROM   survey_response a) a
WHERE  PurcahseYnSum = 2
group by customer_id
order by customer_id

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
SELECT customer_id,
      min(PurcahseYnCount) NOofweeks
FROM         (SELECT customer_id,
               PurcahseYnCount = DENSE_RANK() OVER(partition BY cusomer_id ORDER BY survey_id),
               PurcahseYnSum = (select Sum(purchase_yn) from survey_response b where a.customer_id = b.customer_id and a.survey_id >= b.survey_id)
        FROM   survey_response a) a
WHERE  PurcahseYnSum = 2
group by customer_id
order by customer_id
```

Comment: Hi friend even this code works for me I am not getting all the customer having data as below . week_no Customer_ID purchase_yn
201728 87697 1
201728 87697 1
201728 87697 1
201732 87697 1
201733 87697 0
201742 87697 0
201743 87697 1